# Redirect URL via htaccess unique destination for subdirectories

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect URLs of a old Perch CMS to a custom CMS like this:

```
Redirect /sites/praxis/   http://example.com/_Unser_Cabinet
Redirect /sites/praxis/sites/chiropraktik   http://example.com/_Unser_Cabinet
```

In this case the subfolder of praxis should redirect to the same URL but instead it ends up here:

```
http://example.com/_Unser_Cabinet/sites/chiropraktik
```

and

```
Redirect /sites/behandlungen/   http://chirohelias.com/_Was_ist_Chiropraktik
Redirect /sites/behandlungen/sauglingekinder/  http://chirohelias.com/_Chiropraktik_fur_Neugeborene_und_Kinder
```

In this case the subfolder should end up at a different URL with similar results it ends up here:

```
http://example.com/_Was_ist_Chiropraktiksauglingekinder/
```

I understand that its taking the first redirect and applying it to the second URL but I cant figure out the logic to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive is designed to preserve the rest of the path across the redirect.   If you don't want this behavior, you can use `RedirectMatch` instead which give you a lot more control:

```
RedirectMatch /sites/praxis.* http://example.com/_Unser_Cabinet
```

the `.*` matches any URL under that path and redirects any of them to the new URL without anything appended.  If you wanted to use the path, you would need to use `$1` in the final URL as a placeholder.  See the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

I didn't put a trailing slash on `praxis/` because you probably want to redirect the URL without the trailing slash.  However if you have a URL like `/sites/proxisxyzzy` that you *don't* want to redirect, you should use the slash.

Another workaround would be to reverse the order of your directives.

```
Redirect /sites/praxis/sites/chiropraktik   http://example.com/_Unser_Cabinet
Redirect /sites/praxis/   http://example.com/_Unser_Cabinet
```

The redirect directives are executed in order until one matches.  When the most specific one is first, it takes precedence.   The drawback to this approach is that you would have to write lots of specific rules first, followed by a general rule for the directory.