# Redirecting to new domain page by page

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects

I'm trying to redirect a domain to another one. Because of SEO concerns I've made a list of all the pages indexed in Google and for each one I decided where to redirect to. My .htaccess looks like this ([full version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e47G74OhjIh_Yf4VedzRkjW0rUF4kVruOf6LSvpCAB8/edit?usp=sharing)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /webshop https://example.com/winkel/
Redirect 301 /vacatures https://example.com/vacatures/
Redirect 301 /uw-aanvraag-is-succesvol-verzonden https://example.com
Redirect 301 /sitemap https://example.com
# snip rules here ...
Redirect 301 /behandelingen/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/ooglidcorrectie--amsterdam https://example.com/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/
Redirect 301 /behandelingen/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie https://example.com/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/
Redirect 301 /behandelingen/chirurgisch https://example.com/chirurgisch/
Redirect 301 /behandelingen https://example.com
# snip rules here ...
Redirect 301 /aandoeningen https://example.com
Redirect 301 /404 https://example.com
</IfModule>
```

For a lot of pages it is working as intended but somehow for some pages it doesn't.

Working:
`/behandelingen/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/ooglidcorrectie-amsterdam` is redirecting to `https://example.com/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/`

The version with two dashes is not working:
`/behandelingen/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/ooglidcorrectie--amsterdam` is redirecting to `https://example.com/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/ooglidcorrectie--amsterdam` while it should also redirect to `https://example.com/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/`

Somehow it adds the last slug `ooglidcorrectie--amsterdam` even though I have `https://example.com/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/`  in my *.htaccess*

Comment: Somebody had a similar problem, but your rules look like they are in the correct order: [Redirect URL via htaccess unique destination for subdirectories](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/redirect-url-via-htaccess-unique-destination-for-subdirectories)

Comment: For SEO, redirects to the home page are useless.   Google treats redirects to the home page just like 404 errors.  They will show up in Google Search Console in the "soft 404" error report.    If you don't have direct replacement for a URL, it it usually better user experience to show a "404 not found" error rather than redirect to the home page.  At least then users know that what they are looking for isn't there and don't have to spend time reading the home page before realizing that what they are looking for is not there.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` because you are not using rewrite rules.   The `Redirect` directive is from [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html), not from `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Your redirects appear to be working for me:  `curl --head https://www.huisartskliniek.nl/behandelingen/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/ooglidcorrectie--amsterdam` shows `Location: https://ivyclinics.nl/chirurgisch/ooglidcorrectie/`.   I suspect that the problem may have come from an old version of your rules and that when you tested them your browser cached the old redirects.   Can you test using `curl` on the command line, or try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I checked on some other devices and it appears to be working. It was indeed some caching thing. Also very good advise on the soft 404's, I'll create some better pages for those.